# Delete Powerpoint Slides containing keywords using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a folder with 10 PowerPoint presentations. Each presentation has 20-25 slides.

Suppose I have a keyword "CX404","AR50". The macro should delete all slides having that keyword in the 10 presentations.

```
Public Sub DoFiles()
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strFolderName As String
    Dim PP As Presentation
    'set default directory here if needed
    strFolderName = "D:\Users\Desktop\Shaon\pptss"
    strFileName = Dir(strFolderName & "\*.pptx*")
    Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
        Set PP = Presentations.Open(strFolderName & "\" & strFileName)
        'your code
        Dim oSld As Slide
        Dim oShp As Shape
        Dim L As Long
        For L = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count To 1 Step -1
            Set oSld = ActivePresentation.Slides(L)
            For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
                If oShp.HasTextFrame Then
                    Select Case UCase(oShp.TextFrame.TextRange)
                    Case Is = "CX400", "AR50"
                        oSld.Delete
                    Case Else
                       'not found
                End Select
                End If
            Next oShp
        Next L
        PP.Close
        strFileName = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

I can open all ppts in the folder. I am not be able to delete slides using my specific keywords.

Comment: welcome. You came too close from your previous post. May try `instr` function to check occurrence of Keywords  within the text in the shapes. Also do not forget to use `Exit for` after deleting the slide to avoid error attempting to .find shapes in deleted slide. this will work with shapes without groups and nodes within it (refer the last example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have slightly modified your listing and it works for me:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub DoFiles()
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strFolderName As String
    Dim PP As Presentation
    Dim sText As String
    strFolderName = "D:\111\"
    strFileName = Dir(strFolderName & "\*.pptx*")
    sText = "TEST"
    Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
        Set PP = Presentations.Open(strFolderName & "\" & strFileName)
        Dim oSld As Slide
        Dim oShp As Shape
        Dim L As Long
        For L = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set oSld = ActivePresentation.Slides(L)
             For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
             On Error Resume Next
                If oShp.HasTextFrame Then
                    If UBound(Split(oShp.TextFrame.TextRange, sText)) > 0 Then
                    PP.Slides(L).Delete
                    End If
                End If
             Next oShp
        Next L
        PP.Save
        PP.Close
        strFileName = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: In my case when I use your code above PP.Slides(L).Delete its not work inside the loop.Inside the loop this line didn't execute

Comment: I changed listing above, you can try it one more time. Set your text to search into sText variable

Comment: Thanks it works..But if I want to do the same for slide header,footer as well as notes  then how to do it? this code only delete the slide where the keywords are available only in the body of the silde.

Comment: I think, you need to check them separatelly and if they contain specific text - delete slide. Here is a good example how to reach headers and footers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739457/vba-powerpoint-2010-replacing-text-in-headers-and-footers

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But I need to know one thing how I can incorporate that code in your code above?

Comment: You can add block  Set ppMaster = PP.SlideMaster With ppMaster If UBound(Split(.HeadersFooters.Footer.Text, sText)) > 0 Or UBound(Split(.HeadersFooters.Header.Text, sText)) > 0 Then                 PP.Slides(L).Delete End If End With between "Next L" and PP.Save, i.e. process (check header and footer) every ppt file after removing slides with text in frames.

Comment: Thanks a ton but I am getting error for variable not defined for sText and also for ppMaster...Can you please modify the code above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189187/discussion-between-sergey-and-shaon).